# Record LineOut output directly to file with JSyn

Tags: audio, wav, jsyn

I have built a loopstation in JSyn. It allows you to record and play back samples. By playing multiple samples you can layer up sounds (e.g. one percussion sample, one melody, etc)
JSyn allows me to connect each of the sample players directly to my lineout where it is mixed automatically. But now I would like to record the sound just as the user hears it to a .wav-file. But I am not sure what I should connect the input port of the recorder to.
**What is the smartest way to connect the audio output of all samples to the WaveRecorder?**

In other words: In the Programmer's Guide there is an [example](http://www.softsynth.com/jsyn/docs/usersguide.php#CapturingOutput) for this but I am not sure how I create the "finalMix" used there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using multiple LineOuts, just use one LineOut.

You can mix all of your signals together using a chain of MultiplyAdd units.
http://www.softsynth.com/jsyn/docs/javadocs/com/jsyn/unitgen/MultiplyAdd.html

Or you can use a Mixer unit.
http://www.softsynth.com/jsyn/docs/javadocs/com/jsyn/unitgen/MixerStereoRamped.html

Then connect the mix to your WaveRecorder and to your single LineOut.